# Does calling a super constructor from subclasss constructor create object of superclass in memory?

Tags: java, object, constructor, super

In the `Test` class I am creating object of class `B` using new keyword - the constructor of class `B` is invoked there:

```
class A{
    public A(){
        //initialization of fields
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public B(){
        super();
    }
}

class Test(){
    public static void main(String... s){
        B b=new B();
    }
}
```

Does this mean that whenever constructor of particular class is invoked the object of that class is created in memory?

If the answer to the question is YES, then in the above example, when constructor of super class `A` is invoked using `super()`, would it create object of class `A` too?

Will this super class object be created along with a subclass object in memory?

Comment: What language is this? Java?

Comment: yes its java language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor does not "create" the object instance, it *initializes* it.  the `new` operator *creates* the new instance (of B) and the various constructors invoked (B() and A() in this  example) *initialize* the new instance of B.